# Adding tableview as subview won't reload data

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have created `UITableViewController` in storyboard, and I instantiate it via

```
self.centerCMController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ContextMenu"];
self.centerCMController.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.centerCMController.view];
```

When later in code i call

```
[self.centerCMController.tableView reloadData];
```

nothing happens. TableView won't reload data! I did some investigating, and found if i set numberOfTtems = 3 before the line:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.centerCMController.view];
```

table view is displaying only 3 items. No matter if I later change numberOfTtems = 4, it will display only first 3 items (althou correctly)... but number of cells will be fixed until the end of time.

What am i missing here?

EDIT:

to be more descriptive, i set the delegates properly both -

```
(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView and
```

-

```
(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

are called, first returns 1 and the other numberOfItems, which is 0 at start and 2 at reload... but -

```
 (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

is never callled

Comment: What matters is what you do in your table view delegates methods, not the storyboard stuff.  Show some of that, e.g. where you use this `numberOfItems`.

Comment: to be more descriptive, i set the delegates properly both - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView and - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section are called, first returns 1 and the other numberOfItems, which is 0 at start and 2 at reload... but - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath is never callled

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is you need these calls:

```
[[[self centerCMController] tableView] setDelegate:self];
[[[self centerCMController] tableView] setDatasource:self];
```

When you are doing `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`, you are creating a `UIViewController`, not a `UITableView`. So setting a delegate shouldn't do anything, nor does it have a data source.

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of won't reload data is that the table view has no datasource set.  Check the table view in storyboard to see that it's datasource points to something (often, the view controller that contains it).

Second most common would be that the outlet to the table view that you tell to reload is not set.  Please check that with NSLog and then setup (probably again in storyboard).

Finally, just to note, the design is unusual.  It's more common / simple to have one view controller that contains the table view, not instantiate another and then move it's view.

Comment: This is like drop down menu, that I would like to have on all of my view controllers... And besides, this is easily recreatable. Create new project. Add two buttns at the bottom. One triggers action to add table view, and other to reload data. Actually I will add this to openning.